# Iterating through a grayscale image

Tags: ios, image-processing

I have used the [CIMaximumComponent](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html) to convert the image being displayed on the screen to grayscale. Now I want to iterate through the grayscale image and apply a threshold such that if the intensity is <150, it is stored as 0. Else it would be a 1.

In order to iterate through the image, I tried to follow the [following tutorial](http://www.fiveminutes.eu/iphone-image-processing/)  and came up with this code:

```
- (IBAction)thresholdImage:(id)sender {



CGImageRef sourceImage = self.imageView.image.CGImage;

CFDataRef theData; //creates a variable of CFDataRef to store data of the image.


theData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(sourceImage)); //assigns theData variable to the actual image

UInt8 *pixelData = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(theData);

int dataLength = CFDataGetLength(theData);



for (int index = 0; index < dataLength; index += 4)
{
    if (pixelData[index]  < 150)
    {
        pixelData[index] = 0;

    } else
    {
        pixelData[index] = 1;

    }
}

CGContextRef context;


//gets info about the image such as its width, height, bytes per row, colorspace etc
context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixelData,
                                CGImageGetWidth(sourceImage),
                                CGImageGetHeight(sourceImage),
                                8,
                                CGImageGetBytesPerRow(sourceImage),
                                CGImageGetColorSpace(sourceImage),
                                CGImageGetBitmapInfo(sourceImage));

CGImageRef newCGImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newCGImage];

CGContextRelease(context);
CFRelease(theData);
CGImageRelease(newCGImage);



//assign the output image to the imageview to display it

self.imageView.image = newImage;
```

}

However when I run the app and the threshold button is pressed (which calls the above method), the app crashes and gives me the following error :

```
CoreFoundation`CFDataGetBytePtr:
0x32f6e0cc:  ldr    r1, [r0]
```

and says
    (lldb) 
in the output

Could someone please help me out?

Many thanks!

Comment: hi your code working fine check the outlet of the image view that your connected

Comment: Not an answer, but as a defensive programming move, add code to check if `sourceImage` and `theData` are not NULL before using them.

Comment: Thanks both. I tried the same code as here http://www.fiveminutes.eu/iphone-image-processing/ and it worked perfectly. Only when I take the output from the filter, my program crashes.

Comment: One thing to point out, as @stevekohls said,    sourceImage is probably NULL. Xcode says : If the UIImage object was initialized using a CIImage object, the value of the property is NULL. In the previous method which filters the image, this was done. Could someone point me in the right direction please? Thanks!!

Comment: Hi All, I fixed the grayscale problem by the method as described here:http://iosdevelopertips.com/graphics/convert-an-image-uiimage-to-grayscale.html
Then i implemented the above code and sourceImage and theData are no longer NULL (YES!!) Now the app is throwing an exception at this line here:
    pixelData[index] = 0;
in the for loop as originally pasted above